# Gradually resizing image inside an imshow window OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Windows form where I have a button, zoom out.
How can I resize the image in this way when I click zoom out?
I tried resize() but I did not figure out how to gradually zoom out every time the user clicks zoom out? How can I achieve that

[image: 2Dhaa]

Comment: Aspect ratio is important ?

Comment: Yes @YunusTemurlenk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna protect the aspect ratio, **its not possible** because there can not be common divisor for width and height for couple iteration. After a while, it ll crash anyway(if width and height not equal). You can determine the ratio according to your requirements. I just chose 1.05 and tested, looks fine.

You can do it by using a loop. Each iteration(click) will resize it. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat imgIn;
    imgIn = imread("/ur/image/directory/img.jpg");

    while(1)
    {
        resize(imgIn,imgIn,Size(imgIn.cols/1.05,imgIn.rows/1.05));

        imshow("imgIn",imgIn);

        waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```